# Posting Integer List Back to MVC Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems getting my jquery post of a list of integers to post back to the action method in the controller.

My post jquery is the folling:

```
    $.post('/Section/RunAlgorithm', {
        test: JSON.stringify([1, 2])
    }, function (response) {
    }, 'json');
```

My controller action is defined as follows:

```
public ActionResult RunAlgorithm(int[] test)
```

When posting to the method my test parameter is null. How can I resolve this and where does the problem exist in my code?

Thank you

Comment: I have also tried without JSON.stringify and with IEnumerable in the action.

Comment: `{ test: [1, 2] }` ought to work?

Comment: Thank you, found the solution in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931832/how-to-send-a-list-of-int-with-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-default-model-binder

Answer (score 1):

I'm so tired o___O .. Here's the solution:

```
    $.ajax('/Section/RunAlgorithm', {
        type: 'POST',
        traditional: true,
        data: {
            test: [1, 2, 3]
        }
    });
```

Comment: Interesting. Out of curiosity, which version of ASP.NET-MVC are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 4.5