# Posting simple array to controller

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5

Posting an array of `ints` to my `MVC` controller seems to result in the value being `null`.

The form data (parsed), indicates that each element in the array is posted individually:

```
ids[]:39
ids[]:54
```

Which seems to make sense as I read that form data can only be posted as key/value pairs.

My controller action is defined as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public JSONResult SubmitApprovedUploadedPhotoIds(List<int> ids)
{
    try
    {
        if (ids == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ids");

        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

The main portion of my ajax POST:

```
// `ids` is an array of ints

$.ajax({

    url: "/MyController/SubmitApprovedUploadedPhotoIds",
    cache: false,
    data: 
        {
            ids: ids
        },
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
});
```

**I would like the array of posted ids to populate the `ids` variable in the `MVC` action.**

I have tried changing the post code to:

```
{
    ids: $(ids).serializeArray()
},
```

and have tried changing my `MVC` action to:

```
public JSONResult SubmitApprovedUploadedPhotoIds(int[] ids)
```

with no success.

Comment: show your complete ajax call

Comment: can you show us your ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a list, I think you'll have to make your data go from this:

```
ids[]:39
ids[]:54
```

To this:

```
ids:39
ids:54
```

In your ajax/post call, try adding `traditional: true` so it gets rid of the `[]`

Refer to this for more questions: [How to send a list of int with jQuery to ASP.net MVC Default Model Binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931832/how-to-send-a-list-of-int-with-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-default-model-binder)