# Django Rest Framework many related field - Javascript ajax - corret format for list of ints

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer class using DRF:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categories = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)
```

and I want to update the `categories` of an instance of the model via a `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` using this serializer via an ajax request.

```
var categories = [1,2,3];
$.ajax({
    url : "/api/items/id",
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'PUT'
    },      
    // Form data
    data : {
      'categories':categories
    }
});
```

Unfortuntely I cannot understand how to format the `categories` parameter.
I tried as shown in the code above and the parameters are not passed to the serializer, the field `categories` in the serializer attributes is empty.
In this case, the request parameter is a list but the name is `categories[]` and not `categories`

I also tried `JSON.stringify(categories)` but in this case the serializer do not validate with error: `{"categories": ["Incorrect type.  Expected pk value, received unicode."]}`
I figured out that in this case, the request parameter value is a string and not a list.

On the other hand, I am able to do the PUT request via the DRF browsable api and in this case the parameter is named `categories` and it's value is a list.

Do you know how should I send the parameter with ajax, i.e. send the param so that is is present in the request parameter as a list an with name `categories`?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer in this question:

[How to send a list of int with jQuery to ASP.net MVC Default Model Binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931832/how-to-send-a-list-of-int-with-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-default-model-binder)

The solution is to use the option `traditional=true` in the ajax call

```
var categories = [1,2,3];
$.ajax({
    url : "/api/items/id",
    type: 'POST',
    traditional:true,
    headers: {
        'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'PUT'
    },      
    // Form data
    data : {
      'categories':categories
    }
```

then the parameters are transfered correctly as a list.
    });